# ImageView.setImageURI does NOT work when trying to assign a R.drawable.X Uri

Tags: android

is related to:

[Need suggestion about a mixed "Uri / int id" images ambient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307374/need-suggetsion-about-a-mixed-uri-int-id-images-ambient)

now my problem is that:

```
ImageView imgView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);
Uri imgUri=Uri.parse("android.resource://my.package.name/"+R.drawable.image);
imageView.setImageURI(imgUri);
```

does NOT work . why?

i know that

```
imgView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromStream(
                    getContentResolver().openInputStream(imgUri),
                    null));
```

work.

but that does NOT solve my problem. because I want to set the image with an uri independenty if this come from a resource or come from the camera ACTION_PICK intent...

any suggestions are welcome.
Thank you.
Regards

Comment: I can't belive that nobody had the same problem...nor there is no solutions...
why stuff like that are not working?why are not documented at all?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Try this

```
Uri imgUri=Uri.parse("android.resource://my.package.name/"+R.drawable.image);
imageView.setImageURI(null); 
imageView.setImageURI(imgUri);
```

This is a workaround for refreshing an ImageButton, which tries to cache the previous image Uri. Passing `null` effectively resets it.

Solution suggested from this book: [Sams Teach Yourself Android Application Development in 24 Hours](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=9780321673350) - Highly recommendable to read.

Comment: Thanks. Android is atrocious, it wasted half of my day. Your solution did the trick.

Comment: Thanks! BTW it didn't work for me on very large images.. On small pics it works just fine.

Comment: @walla This didn't work for me either. Do you have another answer?

Answer (score 0):

`imageView.postInvalidate()` works. Or `imageView.invalidate()` if you're on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

your should do something like this

```
Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://my.package.name/drawable/image_sky");
```

or if you want like this

```
Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/drawable/" + "image_sky");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all see, whether you are not override onRestart method and refreshing it.

If you will refresh the activity the image will not set.

Answer (score 0):

**In your OnActivityResult, when you get file uri, you can convert it to bitmap and set bitmap to imageview.(Kotlin way)**

```
val file_uri = data.data
val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, file_uri)
binding.ivJob.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

PS: getBitmap() is deprecated now.