# Android Preference Image Picker - how to receive result in DialogPreference

Tags: java, android

I'd like to know how to receive a result from an Image Picker flow in a [DialogPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html).

I'd like for the `DialogPreference` to get called after `onActivityResult` so it can use the `Uri` location of the selected image to show as an image preview to the User in their dialog before hitting *ok/cancel*.

Maybe I need to set something at the end of `onActivityResult` and then call a lifecycle hook in `DialogPreference`, but I am not sure.

So far the logic is like this:

ImagePreference.java

```
public class ImagePreference extends DialogPreference {

    View mView;

    public ImagePreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initWith(context, attrs);
    }

    private void initWith(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        setWidgetLayoutResource(R.layout.pref_image_widget);
        setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.pref_image_dialog);

    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {
        mView = super.onCreateDialogView();

        ImageButton button = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.add_image);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((SettingsContract.SelectImage)getContext()).fromGallery();
            }
        });

        return mView;
    }
```

SettingsActivity.java

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements SettingsContract.SelectImage {

    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

    // ...

    @Override
    public void fromGallery() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        // Show only images, no videos or anything else
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        // Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);    
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            // what to do here??
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, are you giving out the bounty? There is only a half hour left.

Comment: @Ajay your answer isn't detailed enough, which is why I didn't award the bounty.  I know what you are trying to say, but for any others, especially those newer to Android, they won't get any benefit from your answer without you explaining more.

Comment: ok, I understand what your saying. I was just worried you forgot about the question, because the reputation is gone for good if it is not rewarded

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you use an `AlertDialog` combined with an `ImageView`.

You can setup a dialog box as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2115770/1985387

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setTitle("Title")
    .setMessage("Here is a preview")  //not necessary, you could remove to just show image
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // continue with delete
        }
     })
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // do nothing
        }
     })
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
     .show();
```

To add an `ImageView`, you could add this before the `.show()`

```
.setView(imageView);
```

You could load the `ImageView` from a `URI` like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9080762/1985387:

```
Uri imgUri = Uri.parse(uri);
imageView.setImageURI(null); 
imageView.setImageURI(imgUri);
```